# Unable to install ggplot2 package in R on windows 8.1

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, package

I tried to install ggplot2 with following commands, but it can't install.

```
> library('ggplot2')
Error in library("ggplot2") : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’\
> install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = T)

   package ‘ggplot2’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)
>
```

Can you anybody advise what's going wrong?

When i use the command `install.packages("ggplot2", type="source",dependencies = TRUE)` I got following error

```
*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "D:/R/R-31~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "D:/R/R-31~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="acepack.dll" SHLIB_LIBADD='$(FLIBS)' OBJECTS="ace.o avas.o rlsmo.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'acepack'
* removing 'D:/R/R-3.1.3/library/acepack'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"D:/R/R-31~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "D:\R\R-3.1.3\library" C:\Users\surjya\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWyq9oh/downloaded_packages/acepack_1.3-3.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘acepack’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes the mirrors take a long time to update, and they don't pick up the binaries of a package for a few days.

Try `install.packages("ggplot2", type="source")`

...which, from memory, often works on Windows.

Comment: hello, I am still facing error for compilation when I use the source package. Here is one error. I have updated the error in my question. Please refer above

Comment: Ah - two options (again, from memory!). Try ````install.packages("acepack")````, and use that trick for any other packages that give an error when installing ggplot. Or, [install Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), then re-run the first line. The problem is you can't compile packages that need C code etc. on Windows; this (should hopefully) fix it